# Trying to sort the posts from feeds based on date instead of showing the results per blog

Tags: php, dom, rss, element

Below is a part of a full script I builted that gets description, images, title from a blog's rss. What I do is use this code for each RSS I want to include in my page, having the results showing like

**1st Blog** (showing 25 results) and below this

**2st Blog** (showing another 25 results)

**and so on**.

My goal is to sort the results based on date and not per blog. It is usefull to say that all of these posts have timestamps like `<pubDate>Wed, 08 Jun 2011 14:12:00 +0000</pubDate>`.

**Here is my code that shows correctly the Title of the post.**

```
<?php
$myrss = new DOMDocument;
libxml_use_internal_errors(TRUE);
$myrss->load ('LINK TO RSS'' . $i; } ?>
```

**This is the structure of a RSS**

```
<item><guid isPermaLink="false"></guid><pubDate></pubDate><atom:updated></atom:updated><title></title><description></description><link></link><author></author></item>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Roughly, here is how I would do it.

```
$arr_rss_feeds = array( 'link1', 'link2', 'link3', ... );
$arr_posts = array();

foreach( $arr_rss_feeds as $rss_feed )
{
    //## Connect to RSS feed, get posts (not shown)
    $arr_posts[ strtotime( 'post date field here' ) ] = array( 
                'title'   => 'Title here'
            ,   'url'     => 'URL here'
    );
}

//## Sort the posts by timestamp (reverse, so newest first)
krsort( $arr_posts );

foreach( $arr_posts as $post )
{
    //## Output your list using the 'title' and 'url' from above.
}
```

Basically, you are putting all of the posts from all of the feeds into one array with a key of their Unix timestamp, sorting the array based on that timestamp, and then outputting them in order.

Comment: Hi UFTimmy, I got your logic here but please explain me what should I put on post date field here, Title here and so on. I have updated my question with the structure of a RSS.